# Any way to receive a broadcast before the network goes down

Tags: android, networking, broadcastreceiver

I already have a few receivers running, including one for reboot and entering flight mode.
However I'm not always getting the Intent in time for me to do what I need to do, send a quick message to an external server.

Even setting the intent filter to priority 1000 doesn't guarantee that I get to transmit before it is too late, though it does help.

As stated, it is not that I do not receive my broadcasts, I just get them too late, after the network is already down.

Any pointers to where I may find some hints to this is most welcome, I've spend the past few days scouring the net with no luck.

**Edit:**
I'm presently using the following actions split between 4 broadcast listeners

```
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE" />
```

**Edit 2:** I realized that I hadn't made my intentions entirely clear. I'm not talking about the Network state itself, but user actions to enter flight mode, or turning off the device.

Comment: what other broadcasts are you using? list all that you are using please.

Comment: By definition, this is impossible. The *system* may not know that the network is going down before it is down.

Comment: I am aware that predicting the network itself going down is impossible. I'm referring to user actions to enter flight mode, or turning off the device.

Comment: May I ask, what the point in sending this message is? Maybe we can find another solutions to this, if we know, what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The best description I can give is to automatically be able to log off a user when they turn off their phone. The alternative I've considered so far were a heartbeat, but that is never a good idea on a system running off a battery.

Comment: It is all a question of timing. I had hoped that apps would get the shutdown/airplane mode intents before the network were disabled. Sometimes I do get the message, but rarely and only if I'm lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this code:

```
IntentFilter monitorInternetConnectivityFilter = new IntentFilter(
            ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
MonitorInternetConnectivity monitorInternetConnectivityReciever;
monitorInternetConnectivityReciever = new MonitorInternetConnectivity();
class MonitorInternetConnectivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (!NetworkHelper.isOnline(context)) {
                //Toast.maketext("Network went down");
            }

        }

    }

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        unregisterReceiver(monitorInternetConnectivityReciever);

    }
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        registerReceiver(monitorInternetConnectivityReciever,
                monitorInternetConnectivityFilter);

    }
```

//////////////////////
NetworkHelper

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context cxt) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) cxt
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && canHit()) {

            Logger.debug(NetworkHelper.class, "mode is online");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}

public static boolean canHit() {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            urlConnection.connect();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error(NetworkHelper.class, e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } 

    }
```

This code, will notify you when the network is down,not sure if it notifies you just before it

Comment: From the looks of it, it'll notify me after the fact, though the reconnect par may come handy. I'll give it a shot though. Thanks.

Comment: I approached it a little differently, but essentially using the same receiver. I'm not getting the network update in time. Only after the fact, as I assumed. From the looks of it, I can't do what I want. I'll get the notification that the system is going offline through a user action, but it is entirely random if I get it in time for me to be able to make a transmission.  Still, thanks for the pointers.