# Android: Advice on sending data to a server

Tags: android, post

I have an application that sends data to a server with a post request. This request can fail, and if it does I want it to retry until it's finally sent, something similar to WhatsApp: if u send a message when u are offline it stays as pendant and when you go online again the message is sent.

Since I don't know how WhatsApp internally works I have some doubts in how to implement that. I thought two ways:

1- Setting an AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter to be executed every X time (like 30 seconds) that checks if there is data to send and, if there is, it sends it to the server.

2- When the user clicks to send some data, I create a thread that tries to send it and, if it fails, it sleeps some seconds and try again.

I really don't like any of these options. The first one is going to increase the battery usage since the application is going to perform operations every X seconds even if it isn't needed. The second one is going to use a lot of battery if the request fails a lot of times.

Is there any better way to do it? It'd be awesome if there was an easy way to detect if the phone has connection to internet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario 2, you can set an alarm when the initial post fails to trigger a re-sent some time later. If the send succeeds, you cancel the alarm (or don't schedule another one).

For getting noticed when the device goes online you may look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11084311/100957

Comment: I'll do it this way. Thank you!

Comment: Btw, I barely worked with alarms and I know how to set and cancel them, but can I know if there is an alarm scheduled? I mean, when the user wants to send some data I'll first check if there is an alarm scheduled to do so before setting a new one, cause I don't need two alarms doing the same. Can I know if there is an alarm scheduled already or I need to use a boolean stored in shared preferences or a singleton class?

Comment: Looks like `AlarmManager` has no way of retrieving a scheduled alarm to add additional data to a pending intent. You could do that indirectly though, by setting a flag e.g. in a db table that contains the data to send, that this is scheduled via alarm. And when the alarm fires, you just send all items that have this flag set.